# How to drag and drop objects and track changes in their order in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have a component with draggable objects (squares). The project uses `react-native-reanimated`, `react-native-gesture-handler` and other libraries. Please tell me, is it possible to track changes in the order of objects after dragging?
The main component with draggable items:

```
import {View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import {useSharedValue} from 'react-native-reanimated';
import {SafeAreaView} from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import Draggable from './Draggable';
import Box from './Box';
import {MARGIN, SIZE} from './utils';

const arr = new Array(7).fill('').map((_, i) => i);

interface Props {
  cb?: (arg: any) => void;
}

export default function DragDropGrid({cb}: Props) {
  const positions = useSharedValue(
    Object.assign({}, ...arr.map(item => ({[item]: item}))),
  );

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View
        style={{
          ...styles.wrapper,
          height: Math.ceil(arr.length / 3) * SIZE - MARGIN,
        }}>
        {arr.map(item => (
          <Draggable key={item} positions={positions} id={item}>
            <Box key={item} count={item} />
          </Draggable>
        ))}
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  wrapper: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
});
```

The wrapper for the draggable component:

```
import React, {ReactNode} from 'react';
import {PanGestureHandler} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import Animated, {
  useAnimatedGestureHandler,
  useAnimatedReaction,
  useAnimatedStyle,
  useSharedValue,
  withTiming,
} from 'react-native-reanimated';
import {getOrder, getPosition} from './utils';

interface Props {
  children: ReactNode;
  positions: any;
  id: any;
}

const Draggable = ({children, positions, id}: Props) => {
  const position = getPosition(positions.value[id]);
  const translateX = useSharedValue(position.x);
  const translateY = useSharedValue(position.y);

  const isGestureActive = useSharedValue(false);

  useAnimatedReaction(
    () => positions.value[id],
    newOrder => {
      const newPostions = getPosition(newOrder);
      translateX.value = withTiming(newPostions.x);
      translateY.value = withTiming(newPostions.y);
    },
  );

  const panGesture = useAnimatedGestureHandler({
    onStart: (_, ctx) => {
      ctx.startX = translateX.value;
      ctx.startY = translateY.value;
      isGestureActive.value = true;
    },
    onActive: (evt, ctx) => {
      translateX.value = ctx.startX + evt.translationX;
      translateY.value = ctx.startY + evt.translationY;

      const oldOrder = positions.value[id];
      const newOrder = getOrder(translateX.value, translateY.value);
      if (oldOrder !== newOrder) {
        const idToSwap = Object.keys(positions.value).find(
          key => positions.value[key] === newOrder,
        );
        if (idToSwap) {
          const newPostions = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(positions.value));
          newPostions[id] = newOrder;
          newPostions[idToSwap] = oldOrder;
          positions.value = newPostions;
        }
      }
    },
    onEnd: () => {
      const destination = getPosition(positions.value[id]);
      translateX.value = withTiming(destination.x);
      translateY.value = withTiming(destination.y);
    },
    onFinish: () => {
      isGestureActive.value = false;
    },
  });

  const animatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    const zIndex = isGestureActive.value ? 1000 : 1;
    const scale = isGestureActive.value ? 1.1 : 1;
    return {
      position: 'absolute',
      margin: 0,
      zIndex,
      transform: [
        {translateX: translateX.value},
        {translateY: translateY.value},
        {scale},
      ],
    };
  });

  return (
    <Animated.View style={animatedStyle}>
      <PanGestureHandler onGestureEvent={panGesture}>
        <Animated.View>{children}</Animated.View>
      </PanGestureHandler>
    </Animated.View>
  );
};

export default Draggable;
```

The draggable item:

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {MARGIN, SIZE} from './utils';

const Box = ({count}: {count: number}) => {
  const backgroundColor = count % 2 === 0 ? '#6e48eb' : '#c0a946';
  return (
    <View style={[styles.container, {backgroundColor}]}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>{count}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Box;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: SIZE - MARGIN,
    height: SIZE - MARGIN,
    borderRadius: 8,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: '#cde9e4',
  },
});
```

Functions and constants:

```
import {Dimensions} from 'react-native';

const COL = 3;
export const MARGIN = 8;
export const SIZE = (Dimensions.get('window').width-20) / COL - MARGIN;

export const getPosition = (index: number) => {
  'worklet';
  return {
    x: (index % COL) * SIZE,
    y: Math.floor(index / COL) * SIZE,
  };
};

export const getOrder = (x: number, y: number) => {
  'worklet';
  const row = Math.round(y / SIZE);
  const col = Math.round(x / SIZE);
  return row * COL + col;
};
```

The App.tsx component is wrapped with providers:

```
<SafeAreaProvider style={styles.container}>
  <GestureHandlerRootView style={styles.container}>
    {/* ... */}
  </GestureHandlerRootView>
</SafeAreaProvider>
```

I need to pass information about the change in the order of items to the parent component, something like this:

```
<DragDropGrid cb={arg => console.log(arg)} />
```

How can I do that? Thanks for any help.